# A value returning subprograms should never perform i/o?

Tags: c++, io, reference, void

I was reading one good programming practice document and I found this:

• Value returning subprograms will not use reference parameters and will not perform any I/O operations.
Value returning subprograms will not call other subprograms which use reference parameters or perform I/O operations.

So, I guess you can use i/o only in void subprograms with references?
But do people really follow this rule or it is not very important?

Answer (score 0):

> Value returning subprograms will not use reference parameters

I have indeed seen it in some guidelines, based on the fact that returning results by reference makes programs less readable.

For example, in the sample call below, how do you know which argument is an input of the function and which argument is its output:

```
centroid = optimize(data,window);
```

Still, returning output results by reference is pretty commonly done all the same. However, you have to follow a strict signature convention where input parameters are `const` and output parameters are not:

```
double optimize(const Data&   data,   // const ref,     means input
                      Window& window);// non-const ref, means output
```

Another solution sometimes proposed is that output arguments should be passed by pointer rather than reference. Thus, in the example above, you would use a different signature where `window` is passed by pointer:

```
double optimize(const Data&   data,   // const ref, means input
                      Window* window);// pointer,   means output
```

Based on this convention, you can guess the inputs and outputs by examining how the function is called, without having to verify the function's signature:

```
centroid = optimize(data,&window);
```

> Value returning subprograms will not [...] perform any I/O operations.

I had never encountered before this guideline, so I don't know its rationale :-/ Actually, there are many value-returning functions that perform I/O, e.g. input functions, user dialogs, parsing a configuration file, and so on.